# Permissions Issue on Centos

Tags: linux, httpd, apache2

Hi I'm trying to deply a webapp to my server who currently runs Centos and I have the issue that I can not write to files inside the public app dir. My directory structure is as follows, there you can see permissions on each directory. The list runs from the index.php file to the root directory.

```
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 myuser apache 102 Mar 28 08:08 /var/www/mypage/public/index.php
drwxrwxrwx. 2 myuser apache 4096 Mar 28 07:39 /var/www/mypage/public
drwxrwxr-x. 3 myuser apache 4096 Mar 28 07:39 /var/www/mypage
drwxr-xr-x. 9 myuser apache 4096 Mar 28 07:38 /var/www
drwxr-xr-x. 20 myuser apache 4096 Nov  6 09:16 /var
```

The server throws an error that says that the server has no permissions to  write to a file inside the **public** directory.

The server runs as apache and the user **myuser** is on the apache group.

So, what can be happening? I have other projects inside the same directory and they have the same folder structure and permission but with no permissions error.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, it was a selinux configuration problem. Found an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/37258323/2573303